# Only allow a specific whitelist of email addresses to register

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a list of 550ish email addresses, I need the registration form to only accept emails from that list. They have any/all domains so that will need to be flexible.

I'm using the [GF User Registration add-on](https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/)

I've tried to implement the code discussed here https://community.gravityforms.com/t/whitelist-specific-email-addresses-resolved/12439 but it is not preventing non-listed addresses.

It would be best if it validates/rejects immediately with javascript, before the form is submitted.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {

    $whitelisted_emails = array(
            'test@test.com',
            'test2@test.com'
    );

    if ( $result['is_valid'] && $field->get_input_type() === 'email' && ! in_array( $value, $whitelisted_emails ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'Invalid Email';
    }

    return $result;

}, 10, 4 );
```

**Update: I figured out a way to do this with jquery:**

```
jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(){

    // Every time any form loads incl validation

    whitelistArray = new Array("test@test.com", "test2@test.com");

    $('.gfield--type-email input').on('blur', function() {

        var emailValue = $(this).val();
                
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="no-ticket">'+emailValue+' is not on our list</div>');

        $('.no-ticket:not(:last-child)').remove(); //remove previous message

        if( $.inArray(emailValue, whitelistArray) !== -1 ) {
            console.log("Email is on whitelist");
            $('.no-ticket').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).val('');
            $('.no-ticket').show();
        }
    });
});
```

The above code will load with any Gravity Form. When the email input is unfocused it checks if the current value is in the array - if not it clears the input and shows message: "[email user entered] is not on our list". Email is required so the form won't validate with a blank email input. There is a description on the field telling them to use the email they received the invite with.

Comment: Please include your code in your post here as a minimal reproducible example so we can maybe get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Sorry bout that, updated

Comment: So it seems like your condition is evaluating to `false`; which part of your condition is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ready ways to accomplish this.

### The Free Way

1. Create a form with an Email field.
2. [Import your emails as entries](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gf-excel-import/) for this form.
3. Use our [Require Existing Value](https://gravitywiz.com/require-existing-value-submission-gravity-forms/) to ensure that the value entered on form matches one of the email addresses imported on your other form.

### The Less Free Way

We wrote a whole article on how to accomplish this with our Populate Anything plugin.

https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-email-validation/

Comment: I do have GravityWiz and thought it might be useable for this - but the thing is I need the people to be able to create accounts, _only if their email address is on the whitelist_.

There are a lot of ways to prevent registration of certain emails, I need to allow registration of only certain emails - deny any others.

Comment: Yup, understood. The Less Free Way above can be used for your use case, you'd just reverse the logic to only show the submit button / display the HTML field message if the email is found.